# Kaspersky silently inserting script tags in my downloaded files

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I was working on a restricted system today and needed to take some html to an internet computer.

I emailed the html file to my gmail and opened the html file and immediately noticed that a script tag had been added silently during download.

The tag is of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/[a 36 char GUID]/main.js?attr=[a 1715 character hash value]" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

It was appended inside the HEAD tags.

I also saved the html file to Google Drive to confirm that the file in the email had not been changed. The addition happens on download to the computer where I have Kaspersky running.

Does anyone know if this is a regular practice of anti-virus solutions?

Comment: The legal aspects are off-topic here - try [law.se] instead. But I would assume that this an explicit feature offered by the product to enhance security and that it is similarly not illegal but a feature to intercept, decrypt, analyze and filter HTTPS traffic for protection.  As for morality - this is opinion based which makes it also off-topic. This only leaves one part of your question: it is regular practice for anti-virus.

Comment: Did you look this up? https://forum.kaspersky.com/topic/why-kaspersky-is-injecting-a-script-in-my-local-react-tests-12819/ and https://forum.kaspersky.com/topic/inject-script-into-html-source-39947/ and many, many others.... Answer: "This script enables KIS to interact with the browser extension." You can turn this feature off...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a commonly asked question in the Kaspersky forums.

Comment: @schroeder: I did look this up, and subsequently disabled it. However I still question the legality of this feature and even more being a function enabled by default. 
Please note the morality/legality is not questioned on the Kaspersky forums. 
The **functionality** is - but that was not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching HTML files to mails is unfortunately a commonly used attack vector.

While embedded HTML for displaying "enriched" mail usually does not execute any embedded Javascript (or only a very limited set) when shown by the mail program or web mail application, this is different with attached HTML files. These get as attachments commonly saved to the computer and when the user then executes these they run within the context of the local user, not some restricted origin as a web site would be. They also execute script and thus can be used to generate some phishing page on the fly, access local files or download malware from a remote system and store it locally. For more information see for example [HTML File Attachments: Still A Threat](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/html-file-attachments-still-a-threat/) or [HTML smuggling surges: Highly evasive loader technique increasingly used in banking malware, targeted attacks](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2021/11/11/html-smuggling-surges-highly-evasive-loader-technique-increasingly-used-in-banking-malware-targeted-attacks/).

Therefore protecting a user against attached HTML files is important. Possible techniques here might for example to remove any script contained in the file, adding own script which takes control as early as possible (before any malicious script in the page) or simply removing the HTML attachment from the mail. It is common that security products will do one of these.